create dynamic intro.js using php codeigniter
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('introSkipped')) {
        introJs()
            .setOptions({
                steps: [
                    {
                        element: document.querySelector('#test'),
                        intro: "lorem ipsum."
                    },
                ],
                showStepNumbers: true,
                exitOnOverlayClick: false,
                hidePrev: true,
            })
            .onexit(function() {
                sessionStorage.setItem('introSkipped', 'true');
            })
            .start();
    }

The intro.js element can use an ID or class to call the intro.js. So, if I want to use intro JS, that means I have to put that code on every page I want to provide intro JS
I have 2 questions

So what if I want intro.js to be global, what this means is that I don't need to put that code on every page I want to implement intro.js on. I want to create a page to add or edit intro.js and later the edited page will change to intro.js?

and I don't want to use the ID or class element to call intro.js, because my output here is that not only the developer team can add or edit intro js, ​​but teams other than developers can also add or edit it without knowing the ID, so is there a way besides using element id or class to call intro.js?


i use codeigniter



Global Intro.js: Include the intro.js code in a global layout file (e.g., main.php), so it applies across all pages without needing to repeat the code.


No ID/Class for Intro.js: Store intro steps in a database (e.g., selector, description), then dynamically generate and apply these steps using JavaScript, allowing non-developers to edit them.


